# Given a right triangle with angles $A=\theta, B=\frac{1}{\theta} and C=90^o$ solve for$\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am doing the trig homework from Michael Corral on page 5, exercise 8:
http://www.mecmath.net/trig/index.html and I have to solve this using pythagora's. A right triangle has angle $A=\theta, B=\frac{1}{\theta} and C=90^o$

this is what I have done:
$$\theta + \frac{1}{\theta}-90=0$$

$$\frac{\theta^2+1-90\theta}{\theta}=0$$

$$\theta^2-90\theta+1=0$$
quadratic forumala yields:

$$x=\frac{90+\sqrt{8099}}{2}, x=\frac{90-\sqrt{8099}}{2}$$

and only the left value gives me a positive value for my angle, so the final answer I get is:
$$x=\frac{90+\sqrt{8099}}{2}$$

And when I plug 'x' in my equation it gives me $0.0083335906 = 0$ which is close to zero but not that much. Is there anyting wrong with my answer and if not, how would you improve on the method to get a value closer to zero?

Comment: Both yield positive values and check the value inside the square root

Comment: Oh yes, with those changes, I get $2.69x10^{-12}$ and $0$. Thank you!

Comment: Notice that, $\frac1x=\frac{2}{90-\sqrt{8096}} = \frac{2}{90-\sqrt{8096}}\times \frac{90+\sqrt{8096}}{90+\sqrt{8096}} = \frac{2(90+\sqrt{8096})}{8100 - 8096}  = \frac{90+\sqrt{8096}}{2}$ Similarly it works with the positive sign